# Como transformar String de hora para um inteiro?

Tags: java, android

Exemplo, recebo uma String com a hora do dia "16:20".
O dia tem 1440 minutos. Como saber em qual intervalo de zero a 1440 está esta hora? Num valor inteiro(integer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creio que não precise de uma classe como `Calendar` para resolver, basta um `split` e fazer uma operação matemática, assim:

```
String horacompleta = "12:39";
String[] horamin = horacompleta.split(":");

int hora = Integer.parseInt(horamin[0]);
int min = Integer.parseInt(horamin[1]);

int minutos = (hora * 60) + min; //Pega o total
```

Pode colocar em uma função assim:

```
public static int hour2minutes(String fullhour)
{
    String[] parts = fullhour.split(":");

    int hour = Integer.parseInt(parts[0]);
    int min = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);

    return (hour * 60) + min;
}
```

E para usar, faça assim:

```
hour2minutes("12:39"); //759
hour2minutes("16:20"); //980
hour2minutes("23:59"); //1439
```

Veja um teste no IDEONE: https://ideone.com/amkZW8

Answer (score 3):

Exitem várias formas de fazer isso. Outra além do Guilherme seria, por exemplo usando o `SimpleDataFormat` para converter a *string* em formato de data, e depois usar a classe `TimeUnit` convertendo milissegundos em minutos usando o método `toMinutes()`. Veja como ficaria:

```
public int hour2min(String hour) {
    try {
        Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("kk:mm").parse(hour);
        return (int) (TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(date.getTime())-180);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Para usar basta fazer assim:

```
Log.wtf("",""+hour2min("18:23"));
```

Saída:

```
1103
```

Comment: Muito bom este porque ele valida os dados de entrada +1

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento peguei o nome da função lá da sua sugestão: "hour2min" -utes